# EF5 breaks when seeding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, seeding

I upgraded my MVC project to the latest EF5 from EF4.3.1. From that point my database would always fail to initialize. If I change the reference back to EF4.3.1 everything works fine. what gives?

```
public class ArticleInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ArticleContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ArticleContext context)
    {
        Config.Articles.ForEach(article => context.Articles.Add(article));
        Config.Categories.ForEach(category => context.Articles.Add(category));
        Config.CareerAreas.ForEach(careerArea => context.Articles.Add(careerArea));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are Config.Articles, Config.Categories and Config.CareerAreas all of the same type? Since they're all added to the same same DbSet...?

Comment: Yes they are all of the same type. What's also strange is that I can comment out the Config.Articles line and the Categories and Career Areas will seed just fine. But the point is that my code works fine in EF4.3 and not in EF5.

Comment: OK. How does the seed fail, any errormessage? And one more thought, when I overrie Seed() I never call have to call SaveChanges(), I think that is done in the calling method (EF 4.3)

Comment: I commented out the context.SaveChanges() line. That seemed to fix the problem as long as my seed data wasn't outside of the constraints of the model. Thanks for your help Daniel.